# Detecting direct instantiation with nDepend

Tags: ndepend

With the nDepend API, would something like the following be possible?

I want to keep a watch out for instances where our object factory has been bypassed and a concrete class is being instantiated directly.

Obviously I'd need to be able to filter out things like:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
```

perhaps by adding to the Where clause type names to exclude, or namespaces in which to check, but I want to make sure we see:

```
IMyCustomType item = ObjectFactory.Get<IMyCustomType>();
```

and not this:

```
MyCustomType item = new MyCustomType();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe such code rule below could help you, hopefully it is understandable enough to not have to comment it:

```
warnif count > 0

let ctors = Application.Namespaces.WithNameLike("Namespaces1*").ChildMethods().Where(m => m.IsConstructor)

let codeThatMustNotCallCtors = Application.Namespaces.WithNameLike("Namespaces2*").ChildMethods()

from m in codeThatMustNotCallCtors.UsingAny(ctors)
select new { m, ctorsCalled = m.MethodsCalled.Intersect(ctors ) }
```

Comment: This is just what I need; thanks for the sample code. Sadly, I don't have the reputation yet to upvote your answer. I will, though.