# Instantiation metrics using NDepend

Tags: dependency-injection, ndepend

Last year Mr. NDepend gave me some very nice help with [Detecting direct instantiation with nDepend](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24655585/5363556).

Along that same vein, I'm hoping for some suggestions for verifying various bits of Dependency Inversion via Ninject. My current shop has mixed adherence to instantiation through DI, so I'd like to be able to both measure DI use, and find specific places where we **could** be using injection but are **not**.

My dream solution would be to be able to use NDepend to find:

- Count of classes in my solution which have been bound via Ninject:
  `Bind<IMyInterface>.To<MyImplClass>`
- Count of classes **not** bound via Ninject.
- Count of classes being instantiated by Ninject (either through direct calls to `MyNinjectKernel.Get<IMyInterface>()` or through constructor injection).
- Count of classes being instantiated directly (by calling their constructor (like my previous question)).
- Count of times a class is instantiated through either approach.

  I've seen in other questions Patrick from NDepend mentioning future possible support for IoC and looked through the NDepend User Voice items.

What I'm after is any sample CQLinq code that might help me get closer to these dream metrics (above) with what is currently available in NDepend (6.1).

Thank you

Edit: I forgot to mention that, of course, I would want to limit all this to non-third-party classes which are "eligible" for DI. i.e. not calls to constructors of things like `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I am afraid the current NDepend version cannot handle this since in code queries you cannot resolve closed-generics-types/methods parameters, and as far as I can see the information you wish to gather is in generic parameters isn't it? You can vote for this feature here:  http://ndepend.uservoice.com/forums/226344-ndepend-user-voice/suggestions/4919844-be-able-to-check-if-a-type-is-implementing-a-gener